# AMD Switchable graphics don't works

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, intel-graphics, ati-mobility-radeon, switchable-graphics

I am encountering a very boring issue for months now. I'm not the only one encountering that problem, but I just can't find any solution.
The issue is that my computer is supposed to switch automatically between my HD7670m and the intel HD 4000 when i'm running a game for exemple.

I own a Samsung NP350E7C.
In fact, it doesn't. The only graphics card that's detected is the HD 4000, and it's not possible to choose the AMD graphics one.
Normally, the CCC is supposed to switch between cards, when chosing the "high performance mode", but it doesn't.

What I've tried so far :

- Update my drivers : doesn't change anything
- go back to windows 7 instead of windows 8 : doesn't change anything
- Use the beta drivers given by AMD : doesn't change anything

Does anybody knows a solution ?